# Excel double click on a ribbon button to initiate macro

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I have a seemingly simple problem in Excel 2013 to which I cannot find an answer. Below I described all the details. Big thanks in advance for any help.

**Circumstances surrounding the problem:**

1. I made a "QuickMacro.xlsm" workbook in Excel that contains Macro1.
2. Secondly I added custom ribbon (through excel tools, not in VSTO) and on that ribbon I added said macro.
3. Now every time I open an excel workbook I have a quick accces to that macro across all workbooks on my computer (and the workbook with said macro is hidden, so I do not see it and it does not interfere with my work)

**My problem:** I want Macro1 to initiate only when I double click its icon on the ribbon. Single click ought to do nothing.

**My research on the problem:** To find an answer I have went through many msdn materials on VSTO add ins and macros tutorials. The problem with former is that I am only a beginner in VSTO, and with latter that I find only "Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick" events that regard cell activation, not ribbon button activation.

**Question:** Finally, my question is: how can it be done? Is there a way to do it with Excel only or do I need to start learning advanced VSTO? Also, I would also appreciate any general tips on where to start digging to solve this problem (except msdn sites which I have analyzed extensively). Any books maybe?

Comment: Just a thought, you may create an environmental counter variable and increment it in the beginning and with an IF statement check if the counter is 2 and then run the macro and set the counter variable back to 0 again. This way macro will only perform the actual task when clicked second time. Not sure how can this be incorporated but it maybe a starting point for you. To declare an environmental variable, go through the link --- https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee156595.aspx

Comment: Out of interest why not go with single-click?

Comment: @TimWilliams My section of a ribbon that contains Macro1 also have a Macro2 button placed right underneath it. The problem is that while Macro2 is a simple filtering tool, Macro1 deletes all selected worksheets. You probably see where this is going :} I want to avoid accidental delete. Also I work quite a lot with Excel and my custom ribbon is kind of crowded (which is why such placement was necessary evil).

Comment: In that case maybe an "are you sure?" confirmation might be easier (safer?) to implement?

Comment: @TimWilliams actually I've done this in the past with UserForm but as my work require me to delete sheets quite often, I decided that constant pop-ups are starting to annoy me. Besides, once I began to look for a solution, it became a matter of honor to find one :}

Comment: @sktneer Thanks for the tip! :} While I already have a solution, your idea is definitely something worth looking into as an additional programming exercise. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Tested by assigning this to a shape on a worksheet (so your Sub declaration may look different).

```
Sub MenuAction()

    Static t As Double

    '0.25 sec double-click interval
    If [NOW()] - t > (1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 4) Then
        t = [NOW()]
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print "double-click"
    'run your code here

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** a side note on use of `[NOW()]` vs. `Now()`.  I saw a post saying that these two expressions have different precision and that [NOW()] is more precise.

For example (also included `Time` for comparison):

Sub Tester()
    Dim i, x

```
For i = 1 To 10
    'make a delay...
    For x = 1 To 3000#
        DoEvents
    Next x
    Debug.Print Time * 1, Now() * 1, [NOW()] * 1
Next i
```

End Sub

Output:

```
 Time                        Now()                       [NOW()]
 0.494270833333333           42891.4942708333            42891.4942753472 
 0.494270833333333           42891.4942708333            42891.4942768519 
 0.494270833333333           42891.4942708333            42891.4942782407 
 0.494270833333333           42891.4942708333            42891.4942795139 
 0.494270833333333           42891.4942708333            42891.4942810185 
 0.494282407407407           42891.4942824074            42891.4942824074 
 0.494282407407407           42891.4942824074            42891.494283912 
 0.494282407407407           42891.4942824074            42891.4942851852 
 0.494282407407407           42891.4942824074            42891.4942865741 
 0.494282407407407           42891.4942824074            42891.4942880787
```

Interesting!

Comment: I up-voted but it seemes I can't give you internet points yet (at least not visibly since this is what the pop-up message told me). Still, I feel proper thanks would be in order. So thank you. This worked flawlessly :}

EDIT: Oh, now I see an update. Thanks for elaborating, I'll keep it in mind :}